# jQuery mouseover event on svg path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I put a svg file on my website like this:

```
<object id="mysvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="mysvg.svg"></object>
```

I want to add a jQuery mouseover event on the path and not on the whole object. So the event will not be fired when I also mouseover the transparent areas.

I already tried to change the event from `"mysvg" onmouseover` to "path" mouseovering to check if it will work in general but I am not able to do it. Is there a way to fire the event only when the mouse is mouseover the `generated path of the SVG?`

Thanks :)

Comment: You will need to insert the svg directly into the HTML file.

Comment: This seems to work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: write your mouseover code in the mysvg.svg file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to insert the svg directly into the HTML file